# How do I use .split in Python to assign an unknown amount of numeric inputs to variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tasked to create a program that counts the occurrence of numbers from 1-100.

The problem I have right now is using .split to assign each input to a variable, but the user is able to enter how many numbers as they desire as long as it is more than 10. I am pretty sure I would need to use a List of some sort but my knowledge is kind of limited and would like some guidance!

```
numberList = input("Enter 1 to 100 ")

Check = numberList.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: What would ***numberStrs*** be when doing `numberStrs = numberList.split(" ")`? And then `numbers = [int(item) for item in numberStrs if item]`, what would ***numbers** be?

Comment: it splits the string into a list so ['1' , '2', '3' ] and so on based on what you input.

Comment: If you need the list as `int` rather than `str` then use `numberInts = list(map(int, numberStrs))`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
numberList = input("Enter at least 10 integers between 1 and 100: ").split(" ")

if len(numberList) < 10:
    print("Enter at least 10 integers between 1 and 100: ")
```

To count how many times each number appears:

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(numberList) # eg count = [1,4,9,7,1]
for k,v in count.items():
    print(str(k) + " appears " + str(v) + " times")
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match what you are actually testing.

Comment: yea the first part is just some data validation. The next step is to check how many times a number appears and display it as an output.

Comment: How many times a specific number appears (you can use `.count()`, or how many times all numbers appear (you can use Counter).

Answer (score 0):

Write a loop that continuously parses the input and adds recognized numbers to a list until that list has at least 10 numbers.

```
numbers = []
while True:
    n = 10 - len(numbers)
    if n <= 0:
        break
    s = input("Enter at least {} more numbers: ".format(n))
    for v in s.split(" "):
        try:
            v = int(v)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        numbers.append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a list of integers and print an error if the user entered something wrong. Go with the principle of "It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission". That is, simply try to convert the numbers to integers and if something fails abort mission. For example:

```
while True:
    userInput = input("Enter at least 10 integers between 1 and 100: ")
    try:
        numberList = [int(substring) for substring in userInput.split(" ")]
        if len(numberList) < 10:
            print("Enter at least 10 numbers")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("You entered a non-numeric character; please try again")
```

Finally you want to count the number of appearances of each number. The nicest way to do this (in my opinion) is the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) collection. With this you just do the following

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(numberList)
```

Answer (score 0):

To split the input, which from what i guess from your question would look something like `'1 2 45 12'`, simply use `.split(' ')`, as was already pointed out by some other people. That will give you a list of the values, but in string format. To convert them to integers, you can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map), which will apply an operation to every element of a list and return an iterator, which can be converted to a new list:

```
numberList = list(map(int, numberList))
```

If one of the elements of that list can't be converted to an integer, a `ValueError` exception will be raised. Catch that with `try... except` to print your error message.

For the second part, i would simply iterate over all items ins the list, use `list.count(item)`([info](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm)) which will return the number of occurences of that item, and store every item, that has already been checked, in a separate list to avoid double-checking any.

**Code:**

```
numberList = input("Enter at least 10 integers between 1 and 100: ").split(' ')
if len(numberList) < 10:
    numberList.extend(input("Enter at least {} more integers between 1 and 100: ".format(10-len(numberList))).split(' '))

try:
    numberList = list(map(int, numberList))
except ValueError:
    print("You entered a non-numeric character; please try again!")

print("You have entered {} integers.".format(len(numberList)))

checked_list = []

for i in numberList:
    if i not in checked_list:
        print("The integer {} occured {} time(s).".format(i, numberList.count(i)))
        checked_list.append(i)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter at least 10 integers between 1 and 100: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Enter at least 3 more integers between 1 and 100: 8 1 2
You have entered 10 integers.
The integer 1 occured 2 time(s).
The integer 2 occured 2 time(s).
The integer 3 occured 1 time(s).
The integer 4 occured 1 time(s).
The integer 5 occured 1 time(s).
The integer 6 occured 1 time(s).
The integer 7 occured 1 time(s).
The integer 8 occured 1 time(s).
```